# WinRT (Windows Store Apps) enforcing to use Tls12 instead of SSLv3

Tags: c#, https, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, poodle-attack

As SSLv3 has been found to be vulnerable to the POODLE attack.

I am using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` class to communicate with server
and wanted to disable security protocol SSLv3 from client request.

Here how can I use Tls12 instead of SSLv3 in WinRT (Windows Store Apps)?

I know the way to set the security protocol version in .Net Framework 4.5. as define below.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Is there any API provided to configure security protocol in WinRT/Windows Store Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to configure that in WinRT. But if your counterparty enforce Tls WinRT will change as well.